# Why do my Bluemix Live Sync icons disappear sometimes?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm building a Node.js app called **MouseApp**. I notice when editing my app, which puts me in the Bluemix DevOpsServices Web IDE, I cannot see the Bluemix live **edit**, **quick**, **restart** and **debug** icons. They're just gone.

It does not happen for all apps though, I'm just not sure what distinctions I should be looking at between the 'good' and 'bad' apps.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why my icons are disappearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some digging and learned that there are a couple of reasons why this happens. All of these are in the context of the app you are editing.

The first cause is if the `manifest.yml` file is not stored at the top level of the app's project. Putting the `manifest.yml` file at the project root addresses this.

The second cause is if the app is stored in a subdirectory rather than the top level of the project, but the path to the subdirectory is not specified in the `manifest.yml` file. This was my cause of my problem. Once I added the path to the subdirectory to my `manifest.yml` file my icons were back.

`path: path_to_MouseApp`

The third cause is that the app does not contain a `package.json file` in the same directory as the app.

Answer (score 1):

When the Live Edit icons are missing, it's because one or more of these problems have happened:

1. DevOps Services couldn't identify your project as a, well, project.

   **Fix:** Create a `project.json` file at the root. This should cause some new buttons to appear in the toolbar: *Create new launch configuration*, *Deploy*, *Stop*, etc.
2. DevOps Services couldn't determine what folder your app lives in.

   **Fix:** As suggested in another answer, you can create a `manifest.yml` at the root, and edit it so that it points at the app's folder with `path: path_to_mouseApp`. This will work. Or you can just move the app code into the project root.

   After you do this, the *Deploy* button should become enabled.
3. DevOps Services thinks your app is not a Node.js app.

   **Fix:** Create a [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file in the app folder.

Once you've gone through these steps, the Live Edit buttons should appear.